# Error : "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while passing values to sql database from Tk entry widget

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to insert values into sql database from Tkinter Gui. However I am getting this error **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**
Here's the code:

```
    con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
    print("connected")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = "insert into student values('%d','%s','%d')"
    rno = int(entRno.get())
    name = entName.get()
    marks = int(entMarks.get())
    args = (rno,name,marks)
    cursor.execute(sql % args)
    con.commit()
    msg = str(cursor.rowcount) + " records inserted"
    messagebox.showinfo("Success",msg)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tkinter Project\sam.py", line 108, in f5
rno = int(entRno.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What is entRno?

Comment: @rogerdpack entRno is entry widget variable for accepting values

Comment: looks like entRno is saying it has an empty value? (empty string)

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to convert an empty string to an int, and that's not something python can do.

Comment: Since you haven't given us an [mcve] it's impossible for us to say. It's clear that at the time this code runs, the entry widget or it's variable is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try and pass in the int value within a try/except block. This link looks resourceful: 
http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/language/exceptions.html
Like this

```
try:
   rno = int(rno)
   break
except ValueError:
   raise (ValueError, print(some debug message or warning issue)
```